# Regex to match a string starting with a letter and 7 characters length

Tags: regex, preg-match

I need to create a string like this `"F4F3434"`

1st and 3rd character should be letters. 2nd and last 4 characters should be digits. The string must be 7 character long.

Can someone point out me the regex pattern for this string.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you even tried to write a regex for this? It's trivial. Here's one for free `[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d{4}`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider mate, you could have earned some reps, if you had answered it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d{4}
```

Explanation:
[a-zA-Z] searches for a uppercase or lowercase letter and \d searches for a number.

The {4} after the last \d says, that the number should be repeated 4 times.

If you just want uppercase letters the Regex would be

```
[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d{4}
```

Comment: can I use this with preg_match()

Comment: I tried it `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d{4}$/",$code);`

Comment: yes it would be: `if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d{4}/', $textToSearch)) //Do things here`

Comment: if you use double quotes you need to escape the \ to a \\. But using single quotes is easier

Comment: This is working for me, but its not limit the string to 7 characters. Eg. this code also working `f3f34562534`

Comment: ah yes, now its fixed: replace `/[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d{4}/` with `/^[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d{4}$/`

Comment: This regex will **match** a string of the correct length, but if you're using a function just to **check** if your string is there is will obviously return true for `f3f34562534`. You can use `^[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d{4}$` to see if your string is ONLY what you want. Some more of your code in your original question would have prevented that mistake.

Comment: thanks. now its working. can u explain it?

Comment: `^` defines the begining of the string and the `$` defines the end of the string. So before ^ and after $ should be nothing